# Notepad++ find and replace within a constant string

Tags: notepad++, regex

Using notepad++ I have the following text.

```
This little piggy went to market, \textbf{smith1774}
This little \textbf{ben1864} piggy stayed \textbf{mueller2867} home,
This little piggy had roast beef
```

Now I want to remove the `\text{}` but keep the text in the middle.

I cant do a simple search and replace in two steps (`\text{` + `}`) as my document contains  `{}` in other positions.....

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do it following these steps:

- open find and replace dialog (CTRL+H)
- make sure "regular expression" box is checked
- find what:
  `\\textbf\{([^}]*)\}`
- replace to:
  `$1`

You can test is [here](https://regex101.com/r/hAr7Gz/1)

Comment: Great, so the $1 keeps all the text?

Comment: it keeps the text what is captured within the brackets (`([^}]*)`)

Comment: Specifically, `$1` represents the first capturing group, denoted with _parentheses_.  https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

Comment: I couldn't get this to work until I changed the replace text from $1 to \1, but I'm using Notepad2, not Notepad++.  Great tip though!

Comment: I've always used `\1`, `\2`, etc. as the replace value in NP++.

Comment: @MátéJuhász Please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59934554/notepad-how-to-find-replace-for-only-to-those-characters-which-are-within

Answer (score 7):

An alternative approach is to use a non-greedy wildcard (`.*?`) in the capturing group.

Search for:

```
\\textbf\{(.*?)\}
```

Replace with:

```
\1
```

Comment: Works for me in Notepad2