# Notepad++ Modifying a string with same string plus additional text multiple times

Tags: notepad++, regex

a similar question was asked on the below thread and i was able to get it working partially
[Notepad++ find and replace within a constant string](https://superuser.com/questions/1262654/notepad-find-and-replace-within-a-constant-string#)
didn't wanted to create a new question as wanted to ask a small help by asking in comment
but my reputation is less so have to create a new question.

I have a text file in the form where the below example is repeated numerous times

```
this is random text
https://helloworld.com

another random text
https://iamdoinggood.com

more random text
https://howareyou.com
```

the problem is to replace only the string starting with https:// to someting like

```
this is random text
<span"><a href="https://helloworld.com">https://helloworld.com</a></span><br />

another random text
<span"><a href="https://iamdoinggood.com">https://iamdoinggood.com</a></span><br />

more random text
<span"><a href="https://howareyou.com">https://howareyou.com</a></span><br />
```

I tried doing this using the find and replace with regular expression ticked , using the command

**find** - `([https].*)`

**replace** - `<span"><a href="\1">\1</a></span><br />`

but instead of only modifying the string starting with https://
its also modifying other text and giving me result as below
i.e. jumbling up of certain part of normal text and also adding
additional html tags to it which is not intended

```
this is random text
<span"><a href="https://helloworld.com">https://helloworld.com</a></span><br />

ano<span"><a href="ther random text">ther random text</a></span><br />
<span"><a href="https://iamdoinggood.com">https://iamdoinggood.com</a></span><br />

more random <span"><a href="text">text</a></span><br />
<span"><a href="https://howareyou.com">https://howareyou.com</a></span><br />
```

any help on what I might be missing here

Comment: I see lots of regexp newbies try to use `[https]` to match the literal string `https`. Where do you get misunderstandings like this?

Comment: @Barmar - I feel to misunderstand things and then understand with some guidance is how we learn.. that is where we all play our roles :-)

Comment: I wonder if the educational material is poor, since so many people make the same mistake. Did you misunderstand this in a tutorial?

Answer (score 5):

You have a problem in your RegEx.

- Hit Ctrl+H to open Find and Replace.
- Set "Find What: " to `(https://.*)`.
- Set "Replace with: " to `<span"><a href="\1">\1</a></span><br />`.
- Then Check Regular Expression in search mode group.
- Then click Replace All.

Your problem is that `[https]` will match if there are `h,t,p,s` characters and not the whole string.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Wasif_Hasan for the solution and explaining the missing part.. Have a good day ahead.

Answer (score 2):

It works with changing the Find string to `(https://.*)`.

The syntax of `[https]` means "one of the letters h, t, t, p, s".

[image]

Comment: Thank you @harrymc.. it worked...